# Guard Authenticator in Symfony 4

Tags: authentication, symfony4

I am creating a simple login authentication system in Symfony 4 and using security component Guard. My FormLoginAuthenticator is following:

```
<?php
namespace App\Security;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\RouterInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Encoder\UserPasswordEncoderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\BadCredentialsException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AuthenticationException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserProviderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\TokenInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Guard\Authenticator\AbstractFormLoginAuthenticator;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Security;

class FormLoginAuthenticator extends AbstractFormLoginAuthenticator
{
    private $router;
    private $encoder;

    public function __construct(RouterInterface $router, UserPasswordEncoderInterface $encoder)
    {
        $this->router = $router;
        $this->encoder = $encoder;
    }

    public function getCredentials(Request $request)
    {
        if ($request->getPathInfo() != '/login_check') {
          return;
        }

        $email = $request->request->get('_email');
        $request->getSession()->set(Security::LAST_USERNAME, $email);
        $password = $request->request->get('_password');

        return [
            'email' => $email,
            'password' => $password,
        ];
    }

    public function getUser($credentials, UserProviderInterface $userProvider)
    {
        $email = $credentials['email'];

        return $userProvider->loadUserByUsername($email);
    }

    public function checkCredentials($credentials, UserInterface $user)
    {
        $plainPassword = $credentials['password'];
        if ($this->encoder->isPasswordValid($user, $plainPassword)) {
            return true;
        }

        throw new BadCredentialsException();
    }

    public function onAuthenticationSuccess(Request $request, TokenInterface $token, $providerKey)
    {
        $url = $this->router->generate('welcome');

        return new RedirectResponse($url);
    }

    public function onAuthenticationFailure(Request $request, AuthenticationException $exception)
    {
       $request->getSession()->set(Security::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR, $exception);

       $url = $this->router->generate('login');

       return new RedirectResponse($url);
    }

    protected function getLoginUrl()
    {
        return $this->router->generate('login');
    }

    protected function getDefaultSuccessRedirectUrl()
    {
        return $this->router->generate('welcome');
    }

    public function supportsRememberMe()
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

But it is showing following error:

(1/1) FatalErrorException
Error: Class App\Security\FormLoginAuthenticator contains 1 abstract method and must therefore be declared abstract or implement the remaining methods (Symfony\Component\Security\Guard\AuthenticatorInterface::supports)

Could you please give me any clue which abstract method of this class is causing this error ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Child class of `Symfony\Component\Security\Guard\Authenticator\AbstractFormLoginAuthenticator` have to implement following abstract methods:

```
/**
 * Return the URL to the login page.
 *
 * @return string
 */
protected function getLoginUrl()

/**
 * Does the authenticator support the given Request?
 *
 * If this returns false, the authenticator will be skipped.
 *
 * @param Request $request
 *
 * @return bool
 */
public function supports(Request $request)

/**
 * Get the authentication credentials from the request and return them
 * as any type (e.g. an associate array).
 *
 * Whatever value you return here will be passed to getUser() and checkCredentials()
 *
 * For example, for a form login, you might:
 *
 *      return array(
 *          'username' => $request->request->get('_username'),
 *          'password' => $request->request->get('_password'),
 *      );
 *
 * Or for an API token that's on a header, you might use:
 *
 *      return array('api_key' => $request->headers->get('X-API-TOKEN'));
 *
 * @param Request $request
 *
 * @return mixed Any non-null value
 *
 * @throws \UnexpectedValueException If null is returned
 */
public function getCredentials(Request $request)

/**
 * Return a UserInterface object based on the credentials.
 *
 * The *credentials* are the return value from getCredentials()
 *
 * You may throw an AuthenticationException if you wish. If you return
 * null, then a UsernameNotFoundException is thrown for you.
 *
 * @param mixed $credentials
 * @param UserProviderInterface $userProvider
 *
 * @throws AuthenticationException
 *
 * @return UserInterface|null
 */
public function getUser($credentials, UserProviderInterface $userProvider)

/**
 * Returns true if the credentials are valid.
 *
 * If any value other than true is returned, authentication will
 * fail. You may also throw an AuthenticationException if you wish
 * to cause authentication to fail.
 *
 * The *credentials* are the return value from getCredentials()
 *
 * @param mixed $credentials
 * @param UserInterface $user
 *
 * @return bool
 *
 * @throws AuthenticationException
 */
public function checkCredentials($credentials, UserInterface $user)

/**
 * Called when authentication executed and was successful!
 *
 * This should return the Response sent back to the user, like a
 * RedirectResponse to the last page they visited.
 *
 * If you return null, the current request will continue, and the user
 * will be authenticated. This makes sense, for example, with an API.
 *
 * @param Request $request
 * @param TokenInterface $token
 * @param string $providerKey The provider (i.e. firewall) key
 *
 * @return Response|null
 */
public function onAuthenticationSuccess(Request $request, TokenInterface $token, $providerKey)
```

As you can see in your error it is occurred because of lack of method `supports`

Answer (score 5):

In FormLoginAuthenticator class write:

```
public function supports(Request $request)
{
    return 'app_login' === $request->attributes->get('_route')
    && $request->isMethod('POST');
}
```

the 'app_login' is the name controller login

Comment: The @sebahard solution did help me to solve the same problem I was facing. In my case, I had put a wrong controller name inside the 'supports' method and except server logs, there was no any other errors. Upon pressing login, the page would refresh without any feedback msg. So, for debugging purposes, I suggest looking at the server logs.